# Create lead from an email?

Tags: email, leads, email2lead

I have to create lead from an email.
Here i create global class and made 1 email services where i gave a url of email
service And put this url into Gmail-> Setting--> Forwarding and POP/IMAP Tab-->
Add a forwarding address.After that I didn't get a verfication code. 
How to get a verfication code?

```
global class CreateLeadExample implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
    // Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the  
    // Apex Email Service 
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myPlainText= '';

    // Add the email plain text into the local variable  
    myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;

    // Check for existing leads with this email address   
    Lead[] leads = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
      FROM Lead
      WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress];

    if (leads.size() == 0) {
      // New Lead object to be created - set LastName and Company to
      // dummy values for simplicity
      Lead newLead = new Lead(Email = email.fromAddress, 
        LastName = 'From Email', 
        Company = 'From Email');

      // Insert a new lead
      insert newLead;    

      System.debug('New Lead record: ' + newLead );   
    } else {
      System.debug('Incoming email duplicates existing Lead record(s): ' + leads );    
    }

    // Set the result to true. No need to send an email back to the user      
    // with an error message   
    result.success = true;

    // Return the result for the Apex Email Service 
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: The verification message is sent to the email address that you are forwarding to. In your case, it will be email address generated by Salesforce. 

I really doubt if G-mail will send a confirmation to this random generated address, however if G-mail sends you the code you can log the body of the emails received to an object temporarily in your inbound handler and read it manually to see if there is a verification code. This will be a one time process I believe.